# Gradle builds everytime I upload to device

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

For my application I have to test my application on three devices. Everytime I want to upload my code to all devices, gradle builds the application again for every device which takes a very long time.

Is there a way to make gradle understand nothing has changed in the code and it should just upload the same code to the other device?

I've searched on google and stack exchange sites but couldn't find a conclusive answer. I've also searched the gradle settings file but couldn't find anything that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your Android Studio to V2.0+ and **make use of the Instant Run** feature to avoid rebuilding for every change.

If you are already on a version of android studio above 2.0 enable instant run from

```
Settings - > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run
```

> Introduced in Android Studio 2.0, Instant Run is a behavior for the
>   Run  and Debug commands that significantly reduces the time between
>   updates to your app. Although your first build may take longer to
>   complete, Instant Run pushes subsequent updates to your app without
>   building a new APK, so changes are visible much more quickly.

Read [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run) to learn about the benefits of instatn run in detail.

Comment: Thanks, updating now to check the answer.

Comment: This seems to work well for a single android device but when I want to upload to multiple devices it still takes a long time. Unless i am missing something?

Comment: when you change device instant run re-initiates so the first run on new device will do a full build (as of today). but then after it will not do full builds every time till your instant run session is intact and you make changes.

Comment: but I'm sure this build when changing device does not take as much time as it used to before you upgraded.

Comment: I just found in another post that you can select multiple devices when choosing the device to run on. This means I can now build for all devices. Sadly instantrun doesnt work when building for multiple targets. Thanks!